# Create db connection with Mockgoose inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, database-connection, mockgoose

I have two docker containers, one for the database and another one for the API.
I am trying to do some test in API and I need to use monckgoose.
I can create a succesfully connection with mongoose, but I get ***MongoError: Authentication failed.*** when I try to create the connection through mockgoose.

```
mockgoose.prepareStorage().then(() => {
    console.log("inside prepareStorage");
    mongoose.Promise = promise;
    console.log("before connect);
    mongoose.connect(url, options, (error) => {
        console.log("error:" + error);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

url is --> *mongodb://database/myDB* where *database* is the of the service inside the docker-compose.yml
options param only contains user and pass that are correct.

The database logs shows the following information:

```
2018-03-08T17:22:44.549+0000 I COMMAND  [conn2] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:223 locks:{} protocol:op_query 137ms
2018-03-08T17:26:14.033+0000 I COMMAND  [thread4] command config.$cmd command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "system.sessions", indexes: [ { key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 } ], $db: "config" } numYields:0 reslen:134 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_msg 207ms
```

Does anyone know why I can not create the connection within *prepareStorage*?

Comment: Do the mongo DB logs say anything?

Comment: @six8 I have updated the thread with db logs. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why mockgoose is doing operations on config and admin databases where I am stablishing the connection in another database

Comment: I don't see any login attempts within the log. Sorry, I don't know enough about mockgoose to provide any further help.

Comment: Don't worry @six8 i have found another mocking library and it is working very well. https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose